# Error while executing `VBoxManage` (Vagrant/Virtualbox)

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, homestead

After first running `vagrant up` in my homestead directory my computer bluescreened because Hyper-V was enabled. Now after disabling Hyper-V and running `vagrant up` I get this error:

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["showvminfo","\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"]

Stderr:
```

I have the latest Version of Vagrant and VirtualBox installed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To solve this problem, you need to delete the folder **.vagrant** in the root directory of your project.
Then run the command `vagrant up` again.

Comment: thank you! other answers did not work.. this one did!

Comment: Deleting this folder removes Vagrants settings, so when you run `vagrant up` you are provisioning a new VM. This solution should only be done if you are OK with a freshly provisioned VM instance.

Comment: Deleting this folder also leaves the VM configured in VirtualBox. Possibly a better approach is to `vagrant destroy` if you want to start over from scratch.

Comment: I tried everything that was said on most platforms but none of it worked. So the only solution that worked was to reinstall the VirtualBox-6.1.26-145957-Win version of VirtualBox (I just downgrade it. the installed version was VirtualBox-6.1.28-145957-Win)